# Firebase Authentication, permitir solo correos de X dominio

Tags: firebase-auth

Estoy creando una aplicación web con firebase hosting y firebase Authentication, en firebase Authentication tengo habilitado el proveedor de Google y solo quiero permitir el registro de correos gmail que pertenezcan al dominio de mi empresa.

Comment: Hola, es dificil darte una respuesta así al aire... necesitaríamos ver el código y lo que intentaste hacer. Inicialmente te digo que podés leer la cadena de campo mail y evaluar lo que dice después del arroba para validar que corresponda con tu dominio.

Comment: Listo, lo solucione de la siguiente forma, cuando me autentico con google el me responde con los datos del usuario, dentro de ellos esta el correo a ese correo le hago un split en el @ y si en la posición 1 la cadena es diferente de miDominio.com.co le digo que no esta autorizado y le finalizo la sesión

Comment: Perfecto, Me alegro haber sido de utilidad. Exitos

Comment: Saludos, te invito a revisar la sección [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), toda pregunta debe ir acompañada con código mínimo verificable, también te invito a realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando realizo la autenticación con el proveedor de google el me envía una respuesta que contiene los datos del usuario, entre esos datos esta el correo, antes de pasar a mi home le realizo un split con el @ al correo y verifico si en la posición 1 la cadena que es todo lo que esta después del @ es igual a midominio.com.co, si es así puede seguir al home, en caso contrario muestro un mensaje de acceso denegado y finalizo la sesión del usuario

```
import React from 'react'

import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithPopup, signOut } from 'firebase/auth';

import Swal from 'sweetalert2';

import app from '../firebase/conection';

export default function Login() {

const LoginWhitGoogle = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const auth = getAuth(app);
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    auth.languageCode = 'Es';

    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
        .then((result) => {
            const email = result._tokenResponse.email;
            if (email.split('@')[1] !== "miDominio.com.co") {
                Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Acceso denegado',
                    text: 'Lo sentimos el correo que has ingresado no se encuentra autorizado',
                    icon: 'error',
                    allowEscapeKey: false,
                    allowOutsideClick: false,
                    confirmButtonColor: '#40CFFF',
                    confirmButtonText: 'CONTINUAR'
                }).then(() => {
                    signOut(auth)
                        .then(() => {
                            window.location.href = '/';
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            console.log(error);
                        });
                })
            } else {
                localStorage.setItem('email', email);
                window.location.href = '/';
            };
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
};
return ();
}
```

Comment: Las respuestas que son solo código son consideradas de baja calidad, por favor explica cómo esto da solución a la pregunta planteada, recuerda que las respuestas deben ayudar también a otros usuarios, por favor lee [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). ;)